# Setting the Height of an KendoUI MVC ComboBox

Tags: css, kendo-ui

The defaults for the MVC ComboBox Control are too large & want to set the height to be smaller.  I have looked at various online & tried them to no avail.

I want to **set the height to 30px**.  They use EM, so I have **converted it to 1.90em**.

[image]

THINGS I HAVE TRIED ALREADY...

1. I tried setting `.k-input { height: 1.875em; } .k-select { height: 1.875em; }`
2. I tried setting `.Height(30)` in the MVC control (itself)
3. I tried setting `.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 30px; width:100%;" }))`

**Q:** What is the correct method of setting the height?

**SAMPLE MVC CONTROL:**

```
@(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
  .Name("ddlDeviceType")
  .Filter("contains")
  .Placeholder("Select Device Type...")
  .DataTextField("Text")
  .DataValueField("Value")
  .BindTo(new List<SelectListItem>() {
      new SelectListItem() { Text = "Bristol-3330", Value = "1" },
      new SelectListItem() { Text = "Eagle", Value = "2" },
      new SelectListItem() { Text = "Flow Automation-Autopilot", Value = "3" },
      new SelectListItem() { Text = "ROC-300 FLASHPAC", Value = "4" }
  })
  .Suggest(true)
  .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%;" }))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several CSS selectors that you need to use, in order to reduce the height of several nested elements.

**YOUR REQUIREMENTS WOULD LOOK LIKE:**

```
.k-dropdown-wrap {
    border-radius: 0px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.k-combobox .k-input {
    height: 2em;
}

.k-dropdown-wrap .k-select {
    line-height: 2em;
    min-height: 1em;
}
.k-combobox .k-dropdown-wrap:before {
    height: 1em;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}

.k-webkit .k-combobox .k-dropdown-wrap:before {
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

ALSO...
Here is an online example you can use:
http://dojo.telerik.com/OvaWE

Comment: This is perfect.  If it is okay, when I fix it to my "specs" I will update your answer to those specifications & mark it correct

Comment: NOTE: Make sure to change "line-height" to something only-slightly above 1

Comment: While I really like KendoUI, Telerik/Progress sometimes really disappoints me! I've been struggling for hours to set something as simple as the height of a widget. Unbelievable. This guy deserves a beer. +1

Comment: Btw.. Is there any way to adapt the height of k-textbox in order to fit the size of the widgets set by the css code you pointed out above?

Comment: @Alan Thanks :) Is this what you are after? http://dojo.telerik.com/ICiHUH It is possible to match k-textbox and ComboBox height, but you will need to adjust the CSS heights manually.